# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 next to Windows 7 on a SATA drive set to RAID

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb-installation

I know there are a lot of similar installation questions but I have tried multiple solutions posted in them and can't figure this out.

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a partitioned HDD with Windows 7 on another partition. The SATA controller for the HDD is set to RAID but there is only one HDD. I just recently reinstalled Windows and I somehow had the SATA controller default to RAID without paying attention even though I don't need it.

The Ubuntu installer recognizes the HDD but it thinks it is one big 1TB space and doesn't detect the presence of Windows or the partitions. Gparted recognizes the partitions if I start Ubuntu from the USB key.

I am hoping to avoid reinstalling Windows in addition to Ubuntu in order to change the setting away from RAID. Any ideas?

Thank you for any help.